# Titanium oAuth Request

Tags: oauth, titanium, appcelerator

I have a Titanium Appcelerator project and I am trying to incorporate an API that uses oAuth. I found an excellent implementation of oAuth in Titanium Appcelerator for SimpleGeo by Aaron Saunders over at his blog:

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/3321606289/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-oauth-and-simplegeo

It is extremely simplified and boiled down so I figured it would be easy to transfer the implementation to other APIs. In my case, I would like to extend it to Quizlet's API found here:

https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/authorization_code_flow/

However, I am afraid I am just too new to oAuth in general that I don't even know where to begin, especially in how and what to do to the parameters. I'm hoping it's as simple as changing some parameters around.

It would be terrific if an expert could spare some time and maybe explain how I would go about adapting the implementation for Quizlet's API.

Thank you so much in advance. Please let me know if you would like me to paste in the code from Aaron's blog or do anything. I didn't want to clutter this post.

Comment: What actually you need to know in this question? Aaron Saunders blog has the example of making an API call and how to set the params in it.

Comment: As Muhammad said, Aaron's blog has a good example of API calls. Without additional information on the project theres little extra information anyone can provide you with. Your best bet would be to look at Appceletators own Q&A area as its likely that someone has asked about oAuth before. If I recall there is also an oAuth helper now in the Appcelerator Marketplace, might be worth a look.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone could show me an example of how to use Quizlet's API parameters instead of SimpleGeo's in this example.